# Sincerity with good deeds

Tags: allah

I have been having problems controlling my intentions while doing good deeds. I was wondering if anyone had any tips on making sure that my intention is pure. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for advice.

Comment: _https://ahlehadith.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/the-purification-of-the-soul.pdf_   This book can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you do any good deeds, you will find a little sensation of being superior to others,being a hero, this has nothing to do with your intentions, it's just natural.
bad intentions is when you do good deeds and announce the news everywhere. on every occasion and meetings.

Answer (score 0):

( Purifying the heart)

"Verily, he who has purified the heart is successful and he who has despoiled it has lost."

A lot of people have misunderstandings about purifying. Many think that it is something beyond Qur'an and Sunnah.

Purity is the soul of Islam.

Its function is to purify the heart from the lowly bestial attributes of lust, calamities of the tongue, anger, malice, jealousy, love of the world, love of fame, niggardliness, greed, ostentation, vanity, deception, etc.

At the same time it aims at the adornment of the heart with the lofty attributes of repentance, perseverance, gratefulness, fear of Allah, hope, abstention,  trust, love, sincerity, truth, contemplation, etc.

Follow these and your intentions will be pure